# Animations not playing in Unity 5.3.4f1 (C#)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am making a 2D Android game in Unity 5.3.4f1 using C# and have tried nearly everything to get my animations to play. I have tried the following (and possibly more)

- Setting the animation to legacy
- Using an animation component
- Using an animator component
- Using an animation controller
- Various bits of code

Please help me start my animations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shows us some code and screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! Using an Animator Controller, I was able to make my animations play by making a state in the controller that uses the animation clip I wanted to play, then making a transition to that state with a trigger as a condition. I then used the function `animator.SetTrigger ("triggerName");` to set off the trigger and play the animation. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you are using Unity UI.

Let's assume that you have nothing but a Main Camera at default settings in your scene.

Add a canvas as a child.
Add an image as a child of the canvas. 
Select "Image" in your project hierarchy.
Now, go to Window in the top panel and select Animation.
You will see a dialoge that says,
   "To begin animating Image, create an Animator and an Animation Clip."

Click Create.
Click Add property.
Click the Image drop down and
   select color's "plus sign."
Drag the red bar to 0:30
Change the color in the Image object using the color dialogue menu.

Voila. Animated image.

You can then make a parameter for this in the Animator window if you so choose. See this example. [Animation Parameters](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html)

Comment: Okay, I was not that descriptive. I am using unity editor 5.3.4f1 and am trying to animate a button and text when the button is pressed. I will post a screenshot later as an edit to the question.